# Two lists + two conditions

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to connect two lists and two conditions... My way doesn't work and I have no idea how to get it right.

What I want:

Find terms of triggerlist in file. 
If the have been found, find citylist terms. 
Only if this combination is found, print success

All my following approaches do not work…

```
triggerlist = ["hotel", "venue"]
citylist = ["austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"]

with open(filename, 'r') as myself:
    for word in words(myself):

    for i in triggerlist and citylist:
          if i in word:
              print ('SUCCESS')

    for i in triggerlist:
          if i in word and triggerlist:
              print ('SUCCESS')

    for i in triggerlist:
          if i in word 
             if i in triggerlist:
             print ('SUCCESS')
```

UPDATE:

As it seems I was not clear enough (but I thought I was), here another brief description of what I want:

```html
textfromfile = ["A log line of text containing several words"]
triggerlist = ["hotel", "venue"]
citylist = ["austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"]

if word from triggerlist is in textfromfile:
    print 'nice'

if word from triggerlist AND word from citylist is in textfromfile:
    print 'what I want'
```

Is it now better to understand what I want?

Comment: Well, obviously this code does not make any sense. `and` is a boolean operator, and half of your variables are undefined in for loops.

You could elaborate on what output you want to get (what are the conditions), as I find it hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Your first check compares citylist as a boolean, and does not concatenate the two lists.  Are you looking for overlaps in the two lists, or just whether a certain word exists in both lists?

Comment: I edited and hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It's not clear yet - does the file contain a list of words?  And you're trying to print "success" only if the word is in BOTH trigger and city lists?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: The file contains a long string of multiple text. I split them through a generator. The output is "word", which contains multiple lines of words, that I want to check with first the triggerlist and then, when the triggers are found, also the citylist. Example: Success only if "hotel" and "germany" has been found. Not only "hotel".

Comment: Do the lines follow a particular structure? Ex. trigger first, city second? `austria hotel`

Comment: I edited once again. I think nobody really understood, what I wanted to do. Sorry for that. Hope the Addon clears up!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find words which appear in both of triggerlist and citylist, you can run

```
triggerlist = ["hotel", "venue"]
citylist = ["hotel", "austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"]
word = ["hotel"]

for w in word:
    if w in triggerlist and w in citylist:
        print(w)
        print('SUCCESS')
```

Also note that Python evaluates boolean conditions lazily
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: I edited once again. I think nobody really understood, what I wanted to do. Sorry for that. Hope the Addon clears up!

Comment: @daniel_e I am afraid your question is still unclear. I don't know if you want to loop every word from triggerlist and citylist. I think you can describe more about the real world problem you want to solve in details.

Comment: Alright. I'm giving it up. As this post is being down voted more and more as I am trying to be more clear, I am not really motivated to try working out a better description. It's frustrating to be treated like that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to see if any of the triggerlist words are also in the citylist?  If this is the case you can do this very efficiently by converting them to sets and look for the intersection:

```
triggerlist = ["hotel", "venue"]
citylist = ["hotel", "austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"]
word = "hotel"

if word in set(triggerlist) & set(citylist):
    print('SUCCESS')
```

If you are reading from a file of words: (note this answer is incomplete if there are more than one word per line, but you can figure out the rest).

```
triggerlist = ["hotel", "venue"]
citylist = ["hotel", "austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"]
intersection_set = set(triggerlist) & set(citylist)

with open(filename, 'r') as myself:
    for word in myself:
        if word in intersection_set:
            print('SUCCESS')
```

### Update

Given the new information.  You can convert your trigger and city list to sets to compare the overlap (&) very efficiently.  You can put your second check inside of the first one rather than perform them independently.

```
triggers = set(["hotel", "venue"])
cities = set(["austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"])

with open('filename', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        word_set = set(line.split())
        if bool(word_set & triggers):
            print 'nice' # condition 1 satisfied
            if bool(word_set & cities):
                print 'what I want' # condition 1 and 2 satisfied
```

I haven't tested this code, mind you, but it should be straightforward to get it working.

Comment: I edited once again. I think nobody really understood, what I wanted to do. Sorry for that. Hope the Addon clears up!

Answer (score 0):

Found it out by myself, after hours of thinking and trying. As it turns out  it was not a problem of arranging, but of simple understanding. The solution is really easy and basic python stuff. I think it was just a blackout, after too much coding. Maybe this answer helps others as well.

```html
triggerlist = ["hotel", "venue"]
citylist = ["hotel", "austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"]


for i in triggerlist:
    if i in word:
        trigger = 1

for x in citylist:
    if x in word:
        city = 1

if trigger == 1 and city == 1:
    print 'SUCCESS'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
textfromfile = ["A log line of text containing several words"]
triggerlist = ["hotel", "venue"]
citylist = ["austria", "germany", "switzerland", "spain"]
for i in triggerlist:
    if i in str(textfromfile):
        print("Nice")
for i in citylist:
    if i in str(textfromfile):
        if i in str(textfromfile):
            print("What i want")
```